# Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications

Tags: json, vb.net, oauth-2.0, rsa, sha256

The examples provided are for *java* and *Python*.  I would like an example for VB.NET.  I am particularly interested in the `JSON` Web signature piece.

> "Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also
>   known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with
>   the private key obtained from the Google Developers Console. The
>   output will be a byte array."

Can this be done in VB.NET?

Comment: Your best bet might be to see if you can use one of the many available converters for converting between Java -> VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used [Jose-JWT](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) and find it meets all my needs for generating and decoding JWTs. It's available through NuGet. While I haven't looked at the JWS spec you might find this library as a good starting point.